# How do I set the value of an option into a variable without submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on pagination ,
I have created a table, in which initial limit is placed as 5 that 5 table rows  will show in page , I have made a dropdown in which there are five option are provided to choose 5,10,15,20,25 options. Now I want to show table rows data according to select option , like if I select 5 then the data show only 5 rows , if I select 10 then table shows 10 rows data and same for 25 .
I have predefined limit value which is 5 , but How do I set the value of an option into this limit variable without submit button ?

```
 <?php
    $sql12 = "SELECT numbers FROM pagenumber";
$result12 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql12);

echo "<select name='username'>";
while ($row12 = mysqli_fetch_array($result12)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row12['numbers'] ."'>" . $row12['numbers'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

  $limit = 5;  
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  
$start_from = ($page-1) * $limit; 

$sql="SELECT * FROM invoice_details WHERE userid='$userid' ORDER BY invoice_no DESC LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_num_rows($result);
$table_data = '';
if($result){

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $invoice_no                = $row['invoice_no'];
        $customer_id   = $row['customer_id'];
        $start_date          = $row['start_date'];
        $end_date         = $row['end_date'];
        $paystatus              = $row['paystatus']; 
        $mobile = $row['mobile'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $datee = $row['datee'];
        $subtotal = $row['subtotal'];
        $grandtotal = $row['grandtotal'];
        $modeofpayment = $row['modeofpayment'];
        $discription = $row['discription'];
        $sac = $row['sac'];

        $table_data .= '<tr id="tr_'.$invoice_no.'" ><td>'.$invoice_no.'</td><td>'.$customer_id.'</td><td>'.$start_date.'</td><td>'.$end_date.'</td><td>'.$grandtotal.'</td><td>'.$paystatus.'</td><td>'.$modeofpayment.'</td><td><a target="_blank" href="viewcustomerdetailinvoice.php?invoice_no='.$invoice_no.'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ><i class="fa fa-user"></i></button></a></td></tr>';

    }
}


?>
```

Comment: I guess you are retrieving pagination parameters like "page" from query string (i.e. GET METHOD). Same way you can retrieve value of dropdown, which stores values for pagination limit. And pass that value with query string and retrieve the same after your page gets reloaded.

Comment: I only Want If I select 5 from dropdown then this 5 should be set in limit , if I select 10 then this value should be set 10

Comment: Correct, you have a drop-down with different limit options. You need to create onchange method for that drop-down, which will take parameter of itself, along with other parameters if any (like available filters, page index etc.). In that onchange method you can submit the page like the way you are doing for pagination, but this time with extra information related to limit.